# py.test run tests in specific testSuite

Tags: parameterized, pytest

I'm new to py.test. So far I like what I see and want to integrate it to our CI process.

Currently we use a different kind of parameterization scheme for our tests which I will explain briefly:

- instead of parameterizing per-test, we parameterize per class
- say `params` is a touple of of of tuples, each representing different set of parameters.
- we create for each such tupla different instance of some `TestCaseWithParameters` which is a `unittest.TestCase` class. Something like this:

> ```
>     for test_parameters in params:
>         parameterized_test_suite.addTest(ParametrizedTestCase.parametrize(TestCaseWithParameters,param=test_parameters))
> ```

- Each of these classes is injected with `self.params` and runs all tests functions it with those different params.
- This means that if we have hundreds of tuples in `params` and `TestSomethingWithParameters` has dozens of tests, there are *a lot* of tests in total.

My question: How would I go about translating this to py.test?

I've read [this](http://holgerkrekel.net/2009/05/13/parametrizing-python-tests-generalized/) article about the `pytest_generate_tests` hook, but it seems it injects dependency per test function, and I need it per TestCase...

The simplest way would be to tell py.test to run the specific `parameterized_tes_suite` I create already, but I did not find a way to do so...

A different way would be to do a similar dependency-injection at TestCase class level, but I have not found a way to do that either.

Comment: You might want to read [Parametrizing tests](http://pytest.org/latest/example/parametrize.html). Let me know if you'll have questions after reading it.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily parametrize whole classes using the `@pytest.mark.parametrize` marker:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize('n', [0, 1])
class TestFoo:

    def test_42(self, n):
        assert n == 42

    def test_7(self, n):
        assert n == 7
```

See the [documentation on the parameterize marker](http://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions) for details on how to pass in multiple arguments etc.  And also have a look at how to [apply markers to classes and modules](http://pytest.org/latest/example/markers.html#marking-whole-classes-or-modules) for more information on this.